# StringFormat to align on Decimal Point

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik-grid

I'm not sure if this is going to be possible, but I'll ask anyway.

I have a `GridBoundColumn` that's bound to a double property (Price).

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Price" 
                         DataFormatString="{0:#0.00####}" 
                         ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                         DataType="System.Double" 
                         HeaderText="Price"
                         UniqueName="Price">
```

The users would like to always see 2 decimal places, but upto 4 if they're non-zero, and they would also like the text to be aligned on the decimal place. Is there a way of doing this directly in the DataFormatString? At the moment all numbers except those with more than 2dp are aligned.